# Monitor all print queue job

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, cmd

How can I to monitor all printer queue jobs from a background application like PowerShell, command prompt or C# win form and store all logs into a SQL Server table?

Required log information:

1. Owner
2. Document name
3. Pages
4. Size

I have tried 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/parallel_universe_-_ms_tech_blog/2012/09/27/simple-print-queue-monitor-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

Use the classes in the `System.Printing` namespace, for example:

Local:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Printing"
[System.Printing.LocalPrintServer]::GetDefaultPrintQueue()
```

Or remote:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Printing"
[System.Printing.PrintServer]::new("\\$computerName", [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer)
```

You can also use the `PrintManagement` PowerShell module:

```
Import-Module "PrintManagement"
$printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $computerName
Get-PrintJob -ComputerName $computerName -PrinterName $printers[0].Name
```